# How to correctly write statements like "$P(x)$ is true for utmost finite $x \in \mathbb{N}$"

Tags: logic

**NOTE**: I do not have any formal training in Logic, at any level apart from intro to proofs. Without that, I had jumped into my mathematical education.

**Question**: How to correctly write statements like **"$P(n)$ is true for utmost finite $n \in \mathbb{N}$ "**

In particular, I am working with Lim Sup and Lim Inf, and four equivalent statements pertaining to it. This excerpt is from *Bartle & Sherbert* **Introduction to Real Analysis** 4th ed:

> **3.4.10 Definition** Let $X=(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers. 
> (a) The limit superior of $(x_n)$ is the infimum of the set $\tilde V$ of $v\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $v < x_n$ for atmost a finite number of $n\in \mathbb{N}$. It is denoted by
> $$\text{lim sup}(x_n)$$
> (b) The limit inferior of $(x_n)$ is the supremum of the set $\tilde W$ of $w \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_m < w$ for atmost a finite number of $m \in \mathbb{N}$. It is denoted by
> $$\text{lim inf}(x_n)$$

**My attempt to write the definition formally:** Since we require that $x_n >v$ is true for only $n$s that belong in a *particular* finite set, say $K$, I write:
$$x_n>v \implies \exists K \subset \mathbb{N}, K \ \text{is finite}, n \in K$$ I feel like this would capture the above notion, but I am not sure. Negating the above leads to:
$$x_n>v \ \text{and} \ \forall K \subset \mathbb{N}, K \ \text{finite}, n \not\in K$$
Taking the contrapositive of the initial proposition:
$$\forall K \subset \mathbb{N}, K \ \text{is finite}, n \not\in K \implies x_n \leq v$$
negating the *contraposition* we get:

$$ \forall K \subset \mathbb{N}, K \ \text{is finite}, n \not\in K \ \text{and} \ x_n > v$$
So far it looks ok, I guess? The elements that *don't* exist in $\tilde V$ obey the above negation, but I know from intuition (and from Bartle and Sherbert) that "there exists infinite numbers $n$ such that $x_n > v$", but I'm not sure how to concretely infer that from the above, and I am not sure if this is correct. I don't have a particular confidence in my understanding of this (and logic in general), so please point out any mistakes and provide me the right approach.

Comment: Maybe "at most"... Having said that, to say that  "P(n)  is true at most for a finite number of n∈N" menas that there is $k \in \mathbb N$ such that $P(n)$ is **false** for every $n > k$.